# format date time in classic asp

Tags: sql, datetime, asp-classic

Out of the database when i get a date field it is coming out in the following format:

```
Dec 19 2012 12:00AM
```

what i would like is

```
19/12/12
```

I use to have a function like the following, but since the database got changed it doesn't work...

```
    function ReformatDate(val)  
    if len(val) = 8 then
        ReformatDate = right(val, 2) & "/" & mid(val, 5, 2) & "/" & left(val, 4)
    else
        ReformatDate = val
    end if  
end function
```

im assuming it isnt going into the if because the length is not 8 characters any more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use your sgbd's functions to format the dates. For example, in MySQL, you have [`DATE_FORMAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) to do such things.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT('2007-10-04 22:23:00', '%d/%m/%y');
  -> '04/10/07'
```